# Openssl decrypt works differently on different computers

Tags: encryption, openssl

I'm running a single `openssl enc -d` command on two computers. One succeeds, but the other results in "bad decrypt." What could be the explanation?

```
echo -n CIPHERTEXT | openssl enc -d -pass pass:MYPASS -aes-256-cbc -nosalt -A -base64
```

My setups are:

- BusyBox with OpenSSL 1.0.1u  22 Sep 2016
- Ubuntu 18.04 with OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018.

Comment: **Between 1.0.x and 1.1.x the default hash for the PBKDF used by commandline `enc` changed.** See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption/#35614 (disclosure: mine) near the end. PS: you don't need echo -n here; 'extra' newline on base64 is ignored. And not using salt is even worse for security than `enc` was to start with.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 You should make an answer from you comment ...